# I use the following approach to display the page in a new tab, But when I am using target=“_blank” , my params were lost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, url-parameters

```
<a ui-sref="app.reports.equipmentarg({factoryId: fid})" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

it works fine and the parameter passed if I remove the target attribute but then it opens in the current tab which is not required. I want to open my page in a new tab with parameters successfully passing using the same approach

```
state('app.reports.shiftarg', {url: '/shift',
templateUrl: 'assets/app/modules/report/views/view/app.shift.report.html',
controller: 'ShiftReportCtrl',
params: { factoryId: null}
```

Comment: You need to have params in the route itself, like `/shift/:factoryId` See the angularjs docs for more info

Comment: In this way `/shift/:factoryId` , param will appear in the URL and I don't want to appear them in the URL that is why I am using params property.

Comment: Then you need to use localStorag, angularjs states are not shared across tabs, if you open in new tab, its a new state altogether

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava is there any way other than localStorage to share data across tabs?

Comment: They are called SPAs (Single page applications) for a reason :) There is nothing straightforward..you can look into `postMessage`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you used the `url` property, so you don't need the `params` property

so you have to add all the needed `params` to the `url`

```
state('app.reports.shiftarg', {
    url: '/shift/:factoryId',
    templateUrl: 'assets/app/modules/report/views/view/app.shift.report.html',
    controller: 'ShiftReportCtrl'
})
```

then in the `html`, you can use `ui-sref`

```
<a ui-sref="app.reports.equipmentarg({factoryId: fid})" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

> note that you missed the closing double quotation " before the target attribute

Comment: I got your point but in your way, params will show in the URL and anyone can change them and it is not required. I don't want to show params in the URL. I want to access them through params property which works fine without target attribute